# JOGL: Strange behaviour with color material for an obj model

Tags: java, opengl, textures, jogl

For a project with a 3d model I was given an Autocad file. I imported the file in 3ds max and exported it as .obj file. So far so good.
But when I load this file into my Jogl application, I have a strange problem with color material. Te be more precise, look at the images below. The first one is an screenshot from my application and the second one, is a screenshot of the exactly the same file loaded into a 3d manipulation software.

How it looks like:

[image: How it looks like]

How it should look like:

[image: How it should look like]

For sake of clearance, in my code, I use triangles and for each of them I have vertex, normal, texture coordinate. So the question is, What is missing?

```
gl.glNewList(1, gl.GL_COMPILE);
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i=i+3) {

            gl.glBegin(GL.GL_TRIANGLES);

            gl.glTexCoord2f(body.body_textCoords[i][0], body.body_textCoords[i][1]);
            gl.glNormal3f(body.body_normal[i][0], body.body_normal[i][1], body.body_normal[i][2]);
            gl.glVertex3f(body.body_vertex[i][0], body.body_vertex[i][1], body.body_vertex[i][2]);

            gl.glTexCoord2f(body.body_textCoords[i+1][0], body.body_textCoords[i+1][1]);
            gl.glNormal3f(body.body_normal[i+1][0], body.body_normal[i+1][1], body.body_normal[i+1][2]);
            gl.glVertex3f(body.body_vertex[i+1][0], body.body_vertex[i+1][1], body.body_vertex[i+1][2]);

            gl.glTexCoord2f(body.body_textCoords[i+2][0], body.body_textCoords[i+2][1]);
            gl.glNormal3f(body.body_normal[i+2][0], body.body_normal[i+2][1], body.body_normal[i+2][2]);
            gl.glVertex3f(body.body_vertex[i+2][0], body.body_vertex[i+2][1], body.body_vertex[i+2][2]);
            gl.glEnd();
        }
gl.glEndList();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just some random things to try:

Are your normals already normalized? (If not, this could account for the appearance of too-bright light. Enable GL_NORMALIZE to fix)

What happens if you disable textures and just paint everything in orange? (Just one less variable to worry about)

Comment: GL_Normalize did the job. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the image, it looks like a mix of having the wrong front face culled (change it with `glCullFace`) and a really bright light. Seeing the rest of your drawing code will be really useful.

Comment: I tried with glCullFace, didn't solve the problem. And it's not the problem of the light intensity because I add the classical teapot to the exact scene and it was very good.